# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle deprecated SecurityContext

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, user-roles

the Symfony2 service SecurityContext is deprecated since version 2.6. In a current project under developpment we frequently use  user roles. Therefore, it make senses to 
switch immediately to the new security services of 2.6.

On the other hand we use FOSUserBundle in the project as well. As far as I see, the latest version of this bundle is at the level of Symfony 2.3. Since in the dev-environment version 2.6 ist not 100% bc with 2.3 (for example if Xdebug is acivated) the usasge of the new services yields conflicts ...

Our questions:

- does someone know whether the FOSUserBundle will be compatible wih 2.6 in the near future?
- has someone encountered the same problem and can give hints to handle it?

Best wishes

Comment: In the new version of symfony2 SecurityContext has been splitted in two pieces, but there are not bc. FOSUserBundle should work well with 2.6. Symfony will trigger an E_USER_DEPRECATED error, but you can ignore it for now.

Comment: You can use $this->container->get('security.token_storage') from now on.

Comment: please ask it directly on the github repo

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved.

First of all it turned out that all the Deprecated-errors - which prevented a development in our current envirement/configuration - came from a Symfony 2.7-dev version.

It seems that Symfony 2.6 itself does not have such errors. In this sense the above comments were correct. Thus, for the moment one has to use Symfony 2.6 in order to rewrite the own app such that the usage of security aspects becomes compatible with version 2.6.

From a FOS-developer we got the feedback that there will be an 2.6 compatible update of the user bundle before the release of a stable Symfony 2.7 vesion. Therefor one  can switch smoothly form 2.6 to 2.7.